# Payara 4.1.2.181 compatibility with Java 7

Tags: payara

I can't run payara 4.1.2.181 with java 7 (Orracle jdk 1.7.0_80).
I have no problem with java 8 and the previous build of Payara (4.1.2.172) runs fine with Java 7. I couldn't find any mention about stopping support for Java 7 in this version.
The error I got is this one (server.log):

*Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle fish.payara.microprofile.fault-tolerance.microprofile-fault-tolerance [149]: Unable to resolve 149.0: missing requirement [149.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.microprofile.config)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 223.0: missing requirement [223.0] osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))]*

Co you have any idea how to solve it?

Regards
Piotr

Comment: The last one that worked for me [Payara 4.1.2.172](https://search.maven.org/artifact/fish.payara.distributions/payara-web/4.1.2.172/zip) and java 1.7.0_231

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Payara stopped supporting JDK7 for public releases in [4.1.2.173](https://blog.payara.fish/whats-new-in-payara-server-payara-micro-173), as explained in [this blog post](https://blog.payara.fish/swimming-upstream-moving-forward-with-eclipse-microprofile-and-jdk-8). It is still available for paying customers until 2023. So either upgrade to JDK8 or get Payara support.